# How do I insert date in MongoDB using Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a struct with the following format. I am trying to insert `InvDt` as a Date in MongoDB. My dates are in the form `2020-09-25`.

```
type Statement struct {
  InvDt string `bson:"invoice_date,omitempty" json:"invoice_date,omitempty"`
}
```

The insertion code is written as:

```
interfaceStmts := []interface{}{}
for _, s := range stmts {
    interfaceStmts = append(interfaceStmts, s)
}
testCollection.InsertMany(ctx, interfaceStmts)
```

This is currently inserting as a String. How do I make it insert as a Date?

Comment: You can store the date in epoch format and convert it to whatever format you want when you extract it

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this is to first convert the `String` to a `time.Time` type and then use the converter in the `primitive` library to convert it into a `DateTime` object.

```
import (
    "time"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

type Statement struct {
  InvDt primitive.DateTime `bson:"invoice_date,omitempty" json:"invoice_date,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    const shortForm =  "2006-01-02"
    dt, _ := time.Parse(shortForm, "2020-09-29")
    stmt.InvDt = primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(dt)
}
```